# Why is Codium not ignoring UNTRACKED files that are listed in .gitignore?

Tags: visual-studio-code, gitignore, vscodium

I am using Codium, the de-Microsofted version of VSCode and am editing a node JS repo that I don't own on Github.

After downloading the repo and opening it in the editor, I added a .env file and ran npm install. The included .gitignore file already includes entries for .env and the folder 'node_modules', so as far as I am aware, the editor should not be tracking these files. However these files are being tracked. The system asks me if I'd like to add 'node_modules' to the .gitignore file, but it's already in there.

I've read several threads on this topic, but they all address situations where the problematic files have previously been added to the git repository - with commenters pointing out that .gitignore won't ignore them because they are already being tracked and that the solution is to clear the cache, re-add the relevant files and then commit to Git. This isn't my problem though (unless I am missing something).

In my case, the files were never committed to the repo and clearing the cache or even deleting them doesn't fix anything. I am not able to push to the remote repo as part of a solution here.

As far as I am aware, if I download a fresh repo, add some files to it and those files are already mentioned in the .gitignore file, then VSCode (Codium) shouldn't ever be tracking them - so why is it?

I have read through 20+ threads on StackOverflow now that are similar to this but none of them provide a working solution. Here are some notes in response to the common threads that have occurred in the related posts:

Note: I am editing in Fedora/Linux, not Windows and can see .gitignore file is UTF8 - so I don't think this is caused by the character encoding issue highlighted in other posts.

Note 2: The .gitignore file contains the following in this format:
node_modules
.env

Both the node_modules folder and .env file are being tracked even though they are not meant to be.

Note 3: If I run git status, the files in question are not listed in the output (there are no files listed in the output).

Note 4: The files in question are not in the remote repo.

Thanks

UPDATE: I could not wait to resolve this as I needed to work on the code. In the end I was considering switching editors, but I decided to completely delete the repo from my machine and start again (since I hadn't yet made any significant changes to the code. At first this seemed to solve the problem, but once I logged out of Fedora and back in again, Codium started to spuriously detect the files which are meant to be ignored as files to track. So I have not yet solved this problem.

As requested, here is the about text from Codium:

Version: 1.84.0
Release: 23306
Commit: 695a9146b1347633e608f9f166c81b5b2843b492
Date: 2023-11-02T15:23:23.641Z
Electron: 25.9.2
ElectronBuildId: undefined
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 6.5.11-300.fc39.x86_64

Screenshot update:

[image: codium node_module message]

Comment: Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**.

Comment: Hi, thanks for assisting. In the end I couldn't find any way to influence the behaviour, so I deleted the entire repo from my machine and started again. This time I have not encountered the same problem.

Comment: @starball - I thought I had resolved this issue but found that I was mistaken. If I log out of the OS and back in again, the problem re-appears. I have pasted the about text as you asked.

Comment: "_The included .gitignore file already includes entries for .env and the folder 'node_modules'_" Show us a [mre]- where is the env file in the repo? what .gitignore contents can be used to reproduce the problem, and where should this .gitignore file be placed in the repo / workspace folder?

Comment: "_so as far as I am aware, the editor should not be tracking these files. However these files are being tracked. The system asks me if I'd like to add 'node_modules' to the .gitignore file, but it's already in there._" what action are you taking that causes "the system" to ask you this? Please also show a screenshot of the prompt, and provide a blockquote containing the exact text of the prompt.

Comment: I have just tried installing MS Code and it does not generate the same fault.

Comment: what is "MS Code"?

Comment: I was referring to the original Microsoft version of Visual Studio Code, that Codium is based on.
I didn't see your comments before writing my last comment. 
The repo I am using is here: https://github.com/spknetwork/union-indexer-node
I downloaded the repo using: git clone https://github.com/spknetwork/union-indexer-node.
I then added a new file called .env into the root of the local instance of the repo and ran npm install in order to populate the local node_modules folder.
It seems that this is sufficient to cause the problem once I log out of the OS and log in again (Fedora 39)

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the popup, as requested.

Comment: 1) I repeat: "_and provide a blockquote containing the exact text of the prompt._" 2) Please also check your Output Panel and see if there is anything in the Git channel that looks related to this problem. If there is, add it to your question post as a code block.